# Extending InputExtensions in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, extension-methods

My intention is to extend the functionality of methods like `@Html.TextBoxFor` method. I essentially want to wrap the mark up produced in some additional HTML with some logic in it.

Now within my extension method I want to call `@Html.TextBoxFor` and wrap it. What do I need to reference and use to get that to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically something like this

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

namespace Html
{
    public static class ExtendedInputExtensions
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString ExtendedTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
        {
            var original = helper.TextBoxFor(expression);
            return original;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I needed to add `using System.Web.Mvc.Html;` as well, in order to access the original `TextBoxFor` method.